# Does mod_proxy_wstunnel encrypt data when connecting to a non-encrypted backend?

Tags: websocket, mod-proxy, ratchet

I am new to Websockets, and I have the following setup (below). What I am trying to determine is whether or not the communication taking place from Apache back to the browser is truly secure.

I am initiating a WebSocket connection through wss:// (port 443) from the browser to Apache. Through mod_proxy_wstunnel, I connect to Ratchet over a non-secure ws:// connection on port 8080.

When Ratchet sends back a data frame over the non-secure port 8080, will mod_proxy_wstunnel encrypt the data so that Apache sends it back to the browser encrypted?

```
|---------|  443  |--------------|     |--------------------|  8080  |---------|
| Browser | <---> | Apache httpd | <-> | mod_proxy_wstunnel | <----> | Ratchet |
|---------|       |--------------|     |--------------------|        |---------|
```

I know that the initial connection is done via HTTPS on port 443 and switches protocols through a WebSocket handshake. But according to https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html after the protocol switches, "the HTTP connection breaks down and is replaced by the WebSocket connection over the same underlying TCP/IP connection. The WebSocket connection uses the same ports as HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443), by default."

Just because it is communicating on the same port, doesn't necessarily mean to me that it is still truly encrypted, especially when the HTTP connection "breaks down." It looks to me in this instance that mod_proxy_wstunnel is simply forwarding on the data as-is from Ratchet, and as such the data is being passed un-secured over port 443, giving a false sense of security.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same setup except I use Crossbar IO in the backend instead of Ratchet.

I used Wireshark to investigate the packets of both secured and unsecured connections. I could easily read the data of the unsecured connections (as you would expect). When I switched to secured, Wireshark didn't even recognize that the websocket protocol was used and I couldn't see anything resembling my data.

From this I conclude that mod_proxy_wstunnel encrypts the data it sends back to the browser as you would hope.